# Angular left floated button to all the pages for a feedback form

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

In my Angular (version 4) application planning to use a **left floated button** default **all the pages**, for a **feedback form.**
I a, also using [Bootstrap 4 alpha 6](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) and [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).
I tried to used ng-bootstrap modal in app.component.html (with router) but not working.
can help to share any link, implementation

Comment: ng-bootstrap was updated now and it's using bootstrap4-beta not alpha

Comment: what is the version number need to mention in package.josn now. I am using `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",` now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do below ways.

#### A componenet for all

Create a compoenent and add to to the main app.compoent which contains your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

the code should look like

```
<floating-feedback-component></floating-feedback-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

int his way it will be available to all over the pages and you can adjust css to make its position absolute and float all over the page.

#### named router-outlet

you can also have a named router outlet and put a compoenent inside that out let which will avalable to all pages.

```
<router-outlet name="floating-feedback"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here you will get extra advantage of handling the component or you can replace that component in the named outlet time to time in your router.

Comment: Thank u, problem solved.Also can help me to share css or any reference for a nice button,

Comment: I also was amusing to get 100s, but,unfortunately not getting a proper one :-(